# Crystalreports toolbar is missing when browsing through iis 7

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, firefox, crystal-reports

i have designed a web page in asp.net and vs 2008.

In this web application i have  a from which pop up the crystal reports window .When i run the application through Visual studio 2008 and browse it in any browser it works fine.
But when i deploy the application on my local computer through iis 7 the toolbar of crystal report is missing in firefox only but working Perfectly in Internet explorer and Chrome.

Can any one tell what changes i have to done i am googling this from yesterday but not found the soultion.
Plz help me !!!!.

Comment: This answer worked for me. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21139014/1603799

Answer (score 0):

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\2_0_50727 in this path copy the folder

CrystalReportWebFormViewer4 and place it in

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\ASP.NETClientFiles then tool bar will come.